# Is this a dangling pointer?

Tags: c, dangling-pointer

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int x[3] = {1, 2, 3}; //create an array x

    int *y = x; //create pointer y and let it point to the array x

    *y = null; //now x points to the null, therefore x is a dangling pointer

}
```

I am a little bit confused here, since the value that x points to is null, is x a dangling pointer?

Comment: No, `x` does not point to null. The statement `*y = null;` (assuming `null` is defined as `NULL`) is the same as `x[0] = (int)NULL;` Note that conversion from pointer to int (`(int)NULL`) is, strictly speaking, implementation defined.

Comment: What is `null`?

Comment: No, it doesn't dangle. And a dangling pointer is not a NULL pointer (`p == 0`), nor a pointer that points to a NULL value (`*p == 0`). The term is generally used for pointers that point to _garbage_ that once was valid, e.g.  (stack- or heap-) allocated memory (or objects in C++) _after_ that memory has been freed (or the function to which the stack frame belonged has returned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is an array declared like

```
int x[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

So it can not be a dangling pointer. Objects of array types are not pointers.

In this declaration

```
int *y = x;
```

the array designator `x` used as an initializing expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element and this pointer is not an lvalue. After this declaration the initializing expression will not be alive.

So there is no dangling pointer in the presented program.

Pay attention to that this statement

```
*y = null;
```

is invalid. It seems you mean

```
y = NULL;
```

Now the variable `y` is a null pointer.

Here is an example of a dangling pointer.

```
int *p = malloc( sizeof( *p ) );
free( p );
```

After the call of `free` the pointer `p` is a dangling pointer. It does not point to a valid object.